# How to find the regions corresponding to a given data set?

Tags: regions, mesh

I have a data set corresponding to some problem. The data set is just a numerical sampling of $(x,y,z)$ where a particular formula is valid( this thing is analytically intractable that's why I resorted to numerical sampling method). This data set in belongs to a specific volume in the 3-D space. My question is two-fold.

1. Let's say I have some point $(x1,x2,x3)$; how do I check whether it lies inside the above-said volume or not? Directly checking whether the point lies in the list or not is pointless as the data might have a point $(x1+\epsilon,x2,x3)$ and $(x1-\epsilon,x2,x3)$ but not $(x1,x2,x3)$ exactly.
2. Is there a way to find the inequality that can approximately define the above-said volume?

As an easy example in 1-D, let's say the data contains (0,.1,.2,...,1), which means the formula is valid from 0 to 1. Now question 1 is asking if .23 lies in the region or not. And the second question for this simple case would be whether I can define the region or not in this case we can see that it can be defined as $0<x<1$.

Edit: Consider a 2-d case. Let say I generate the following list of data

```
list = Flatten[Table[{x, y}, {x, 0, 1, .1}, {y, 0, 1, .1}], 1]

{{0., 0.}, {0., 0.1}, {0., 0.2}, {0., 0.3}, {0., 0.4}, {0., 0.5}, {0.,
   0.6}, {0., 0.7}, {0., 0.8}, {0., 0.9}, {0., 1.}, {0.1, 0.}, {0.1, 
  0.1}, {0.1, 0.2}, {0.1, 0.3}, {0.1, 0.4}, {0.1, 0.5}, {0.1, 
  0.6}, {0.1, 0.7}, {0.1, 0.8}, {0.1, 0.9}, {0.1, 1.}, {0.2, 
  0.}, {0.2, 0.1}, {0.2, 0.2}, {0.2, 0.3}, {0.2, 0.4}, {0.2, 
  0.5}, {0.2, 0.6}, {0.2, 0.7}, {0.2, 0.8}, {0.2, 0.9}, {0.2, 
  1.}, {0.3, 0.}, {0.3, 0.1}, {0.3, 0.2}, {0.3, 0.3}, {0.3, 
  0.4}, {0.3, 0.5}, {0.3, 0.6}, {0.3, 0.7}, {0.3, 0.8}, {0.3, 
  0.9}, {0.3, 1.}, {0.4, 0.}, {0.4, 0.1}, {0.4, 0.2}, {0.4, 
  0.3}, {0.4, 0.4}, {0.4, 0.5}, {0.4, 0.6}, {0.4, 0.7}, {0.4, 
  0.8}, {0.4, 0.9}, {0.4, 1.}, {0.5, 0.}, {0.5, 0.1}, {0.5, 
  0.2}, {0.5, 0.3}, {0.5, 0.4}, {0.5, 0.5}, {0.5, 0.6}, {0.5, 
  0.7}, {0.5, 0.8}, {0.5, 0.9}, {0.5, 1.}, {0.6, 0.}, {0.6, 
  0.1}, {0.6, 0.2}, {0.6, 0.3}, {0.6, 0.4}, {0.6, 0.5}, {0.6, 
  0.6}, {0.6, 0.7}, {0.6, 0.8}, {0.6, 0.9}, {0.6, 1.}, {0.7, 
  0.}, {0.7, 0.1}, {0.7, 0.2}, {0.7, 0.3}, {0.7, 0.4}, {0.7, 
  0.5}, {0.7, 0.6}, {0.7, 0.7}, {0.7, 0.8}, {0.7, 0.9}, {0.7, 
  1.}, {0.8, 0.}, {0.8, 0.1}, {0.8, 0.2}, {0.8, 0.3}, {0.8, 
  0.4}, {0.8, 0.5}, {0.8, 0.6}, {0.8, 0.7}, {0.8, 0.8}, {0.8, 
  0.9}, {0.8, 1.}, {0.9, 0.}, {0.9, 0.1}, {0.9, 0.2}, {0.9, 
  0.3}, {0.9, 0.4}, {0.9, 0.5}, {0.9, 0.6}, {0.9, 0.7}, {0.9, 
  0.8}, {0.9, 0.9}, {0.9, 1.}, {1., 0.}, {1., 0.1}, {1., 0.2}, {1., 
  0.3}, {1., 0.4}, {1., 0.5}, {1., 0.6}, {1., 0.7}, {1., 0.8}, {1., 
  0.9}, {1., 1.}}
```

If we see the above data, we see that it lies inside a square of unit length.
How do I check now that the point (.92,.95) would lie in the above-defined region?

Comment: Please post some data and Mathematica code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let's construct an example. Two regions (a rectangle and a disk) are defined and verified as being regions.

```
r1 = Rectangle[{0, 0}, {40, 40}];
r2 = Disk[{50, 50}, 20];
RegionQ /@ {r1, r2}
```

Thirty random points are generated in each of the regions and the lists are joined together.

```
alist = Catenate[{
    RandomPoint[r1, 30]
    , RandomPoint[r2, 30]
    }];
```

A few points are defined for checking the setup.

```
checkpts = {{20, 20}, {60, 10}, {60, 60}};
```

A resource [function](https://resources.wolframcloud.com/FunctionRepository/resources/NonConvexHullMesh) is used to generate a mesh while deleting triangles that are larger than the sensitivity specified.

```
m1 = ResourceFunction["NonConvexHullMesh"][alist, 22]
```

[image]

```
RegionMember[m1, #] & /@ checkpts
```

> {True, False, True}

```
g1 = Graphics[{
   FaceForm[{Opacity[0.4], Gray}]
   , r1, r2
   , Point@alist
   , Opacity[1]
   , Red, AbsolutePointSize[8]
   , Point@checkpts
   }]
```

[image]

```
Show[m1, g1]
```

[image]

It comes down to the definition of the region from your points using the right tools and only you can decide what works best for you. For the 3D-case, you can explore `GradientFittedMesh` in v13, but I am running v12.2.0.

Regarding the second question, I don't know if a solution exists for generating an inequality from points, but the world of  Mathematics is vast.

---

**Original**

There are many functions to work with regions. For your 1-D example:

```
alist = Range[0, 1, 0.1];
iv1 = Interval[{Min@alist, Max@alist}] // Chop;
RegionQ[iv1]
```

> True

```
IntervalMemberQ[iv1, 0.23]
```

> True

---

**EDIT-I**

```
reg = ImplicitRegion[0 < x < 1, x]
RegionQ[reg]
RegionMember[reg, {0.23}]
```

The `Region` functions can work with more dimensions. You can specify named regions, polygons etc and do operations on those regions. But in your question, you have said that you don't have a formula for the analytically intractable region. Until you load a more concrete dataset, it will hard to offer a more concrete answer. For now, please explore `Region*` functions a bit more.

---

You can modify/alter the question with an example that is more useful to you. I will either modify this answer, if I can participate or remove this one.

Comment: Thank you so much. NonConvexHullMesh is exactly the thing I was looking for. It worked as I needed.

Comment: I am glad I was able to help you. Thanks for the accept.

Comment: Also explore the `ConcaveHullMesh` function that was introduced in v13 [here](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/ConcaveHullMesh.html)

Comment: Sure thank you for your help. It had been great help. In the meantime I am also try to see if I can maybe find some inequalities so as to get the region.

Answer (score 1):

**Edit**

```
reg1=ReconstructionMesh[list];
reg2=ConvexHullRegion[list];
RegionMember[reg1]@{.92,.95}
RegionMember[reg2]@{.92,.95}
RegionConvert[reg1, "Implicit"]
RegionConvert[reg2, "Implicit"]
```

[image]

> `True`

**Original**

Maybe

```
Clear[pts,reg1];
pts = RandomReal[{-5, 5}, {20, 3}];
reg1=ConvexHullMesh[pts]
RegionConvert[reg1, "Implicit"]
```

```
Clear[pts,reg2];
pts = RandomReal[{-5, 5}, {20, 3}];
reg2=ReconstructionMesh[pts]
```